# How to fix the error Unfortunately, the process "android.process.acore has stopped"?

Tags: android

we are porting whole android open source for the device Imx-6X-solo board.Developing and re-skinning all the applications.Every thing is done properly and device is ready now. But the problem is I am getting " **Unfortunately, the process "android.process.acore has stopped"** " error during uninstallation of the application. That is when I go to

```
       Settings --> apps --> any third party app installed --> Uninstall .
```

Then I am getting this error.But app is successfully uninstalling. Can anyone please help me.. Thanks in adavance.

The logs while uninstalling are as follows..

```
I/ContentGridAdapter( 2576): ------- book pkg name for uninstalling is ------ 

com.vienom.kb.nini
D/FableSyncService( 2366): Tell package managere to uninstall: com.vienom.kb.nini
I/FableSyncManager( 2366): start processContentUninstallRequest
D/log     ( 2366):  ENTERED unInstallFableContent com.vienom.kb.nini
D/Log     ( 2366):  PACKAGE IS INSTALLED
D/log     ( 2366): START FABLE UNINSTALL APP
I/FableSyncManager( 2366): exit processContentUninstallRequest
D/FableSyncService( 2366): package manager uninstalling..: com.vienom.kb.nini
W/audio_hw_primary( 1932): start_output_stream...
W/audio_hw_primary( 1932): headphone 0 ,headset 0 ,speaker 2, earpiece 0, 
W/audio_hw_primary( 1932): card 0, port 0 device 2
I/PackageManager( 2059): Removing non-system package:com.vienom.kb.nini
I/ActivityManager( 2059): Force stopping package com.vienom.kb.nini uid=10034
D/dalvikvm( 2059): GC_CONCURRENT freed 360K, 11% free 7818K/8775K, paused 5ms+3ms
I/ActivityManager( 2059): Force stopping package com.vienom.kb.nini uid=10034
D/dalvikvm( 2576): GC_EXPLICIT freed 316K, 15% free 7755K/9031K, paused 2ms+2ms
D/PackageManager( 2059): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
D/PackageManager( 2059): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 1 services unchanged
W/ResourceType( 2059): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
D/BackupManagerService( 2059): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.vienom.kb.nini flg=0x10000010 (has extras) }
V/BackupManagerService( 2059): removePackageParticipantsLocked: #1
D/dalvikvm( 2289): GC_EXPLICIT freed 358K, 8% free 5955K/6471K, paused 2ms+10ms
W/PluginManager( 2472): Can't find plugin: com.vienom.kb.nini
E/ActivityThread( 2223): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
E/BinaryDictionaryGetter( 2223): Could not find a dictionary pack
W/Searchables( 2059): No global search activity found
D/VoicemailCleanupService( 2289): Cleaning up data for package: com.vienom.kb.nini
W/dalvikvm( 2289): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2b1f8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[VoicemailCleanupService]
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289): java.lang.SecurityException: The caller must have permission: com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailPermissions.checkCallerHasOwnVoicemailAccess(VoicemailPermissions.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailContentProvider.checkPermissionsAndCreateUriData(VoicemailContentProvider.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailContentProvider.delete(VoicemailContentProvider.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.delete(ContentProvider.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:822)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailCleanupService.handleIntentInternal(VoicemailCleanupService.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at com.android.providers.contacts.VoicemailCleanupService.onHandleIntent(VoicemailCleanupService.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2289):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
I/ActivityManager( 2059): Start proc com.android.keychain for broadcast com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver: pid=2613 uid=1000 gids={1015, 3003, 2001, 3002, 3001}
D/dalvikvm( 2059): GC_CONCURRENT freed 635K, 13% free 7722K/8775K, paused 3ms+5ms
D/dalvikvm( 2059): GC_EXPLICIT freed 105K, 13% free 7698K/8775K, paused 5ms+5ms
D/log     ( 2366): ENTERED PACKAGE UNINSTALLED OBSERVER
D/Log     ( 2366): DELETE SUCCEEDEDcom.vienom.kb.nini
I/ActivityManager( 2059): Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=2627 uid=10005 gids={1015, 2001}
I/FableDatabase( 2366): deleteContentName: 9001Status 0
I/FableDatabase( 2366): 
I/FableDatabase( 2366): Thumbnail not found for :com.vienom.kb.nini
I/FableDatabase( 2366): Deleted from device: /mnt/sdcard/fable/books/22_fable_full.apk
D/MediaProvider( 2211): object removed 50
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without any logs. Try to check how android.process.acore exits: probably it dropped some exception or exits with an errorcode > 0.

Comment: Hi Andy, I have added the logs

Comment: Is this line anything to do with your app? 'The caller must have permission: com.android.voicemail.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL'

Comment: yes that is regarding Voice mail and I got the solution.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the solution. By mistake I removed the Contacts app. Every time, Contacts Storage app is checking for contacts.So Now again I installed Contacts.apk. And it works fine after installing.

one more solution is

```
   Settings --> apps --> All --> Contacts Storage --> clear data and Force stop
```

Comment: can you post the link for the apk file for htc sensation xe please

Comment: This worked for me on Android 4.4.2 (Galaxy S5). Thanks!

Comment: Fixed problem on Galaxy 4.3. Thanks

Comment: On my Nexus 5 with Lollipop 5.0.1 this did not fix the problem.
Immediately after deleting contact data and forcing stop android.process.acore crashed again (and on each start of contacts, hangout or the phone app and also unsolicited (as it has been before deletion of contacts).

Answer (score 5):

Backup your contacts. Go to settings and clear the "Data" of Contact Storage. This will remove all your contacts. After that, restore your contacts back and the error will go. This basically happens when FB messes up with your contacts.

Comment: I had this after upgrading from Cyanogenmod 11 M10 to 11 M11. Clearing contact data made the error disappear. However, you need to have an existing backup of your contact data as in this case there's no way to get the existing contacts out after the update.

Answer (score 0):

it is not directly contacts related. 10 minutes ago this message start to popup every 1 second (!). It started to popup after i removed my account from DROPBOX. I tried rebooting several times but nothing helped.

Finally i decided to re-link the account i removed from DROPBOX and then the popup message stopped !

The problem appears because there is a broken link. To some it appears with contacts. To me it happend with DROPBOX. I assume to others it can happend with a different app.

It is an Android failure, not an app faluire.

(I use Galaxy S4 with Kitkat 4.4.2)

Good Luck,
Yuval

Answer (score -1):

My repair has not been posted as of yet - here is another.
Settings->applications manager->bottom left menu button / Choose reset app preferences / Choose Reset Apps.
This worked for me ,,, Must have shut something off that android/Samsung didn't like
cheers